# Broadcom 432b on MacBook Pro (7,1) works on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with a caveat

Tags: 16.04, broadcom, macbook-pro

After installing a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my MacBook Pro I've noticed that the bcmwl-kernel-source drivers for my wireless adapter work, but they will only do so after I startup, then suspend (or close the lid) and then resume.  At first no wireless networks are found and then after re-opening the lid or resuming it from suspend will it work without issue.

How can I fix this?